# SQL Server: copy column data values from one table to another table in the same database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two different tables in the same SQL Server database. In my table `T1` I have 4 columns with 10 rows. I have a table `T2` with 5 columns. I want to copy the contents of the fifth column in my table `T2` to fifth column of table `T1`.

However, when I do a cross table update as the following

```
update T1
set T1.fifthColumn = T2.fifthColumn
from T1, T2
```

It is updating the 10 rows in T1 with the first-row value (data) of the fifth column in T2.  Is there any way that I can copy the values of the fifth column in T2 to T1? I have tried a lot of examples but none of them worked right.

PS: I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You have created the extra (5th) column already in T1 and it is the correct datatype, but just nulls, correct? What are you other 4 columns? I assume there is some unique key you can join on? Are the other 4 columns identical across the two tables already?

I would do something like this:

```
update T1  set T1.fifthColumn = T2.fifthColumn
from T1 left join T2 on T1.keyField = T2.keyField
```

Comment: The other 4 columns are NOT identical across the two tables. However, there is a unique key i can join on and thank you.